# Unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, delphi, insert

I'm trying to insert some information to MySQL with Pascal, but when I run the program I get the error

> unknown column 'mohsen' in field list

This is my code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aSQLText: string;
  aSQLCommand: string;
  namee:string;
  family:string;
begin
  namee:='mohsen';
  family:='dolatshah';
  aSQLText:= 'INSERT INTO b_tbl(Name,Family) VALUES (%s,%s)';
  aSQLCommand := Format(aSQLText, [namee, family]);
  SQLConnector1.ExecuteDirect(aSQLCommand);
  SQLTransaction1.Commit;
end;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your

```
VALUES (%s,%s)
```

isn't surrounding the namee and family variable contents by quotes.  Therefore, your back-end Sql engine thinks your `mohsen` is a column name, not a value.

Instead, use, e.g.

```
VALUES (''%s'',''%s'')
```

as in

```
  Namee := 'mohsen';
  Family := 'dolatshah';
  aSQLText:= 'INSERT INTO b_tbl(Name,Family) VALUES (''%s'',''%s'')';
  aSQLCommand := Format(aSQLText,[namee,family]);
```

In the original version of my answer, I explained how to fix your problem by "doubling up" single quotes in the Sql you were trying to build, because it seemed to me that you were having difficulty seeing (literally) what was wrong with what you were doing.

An alternative (and better) way to avoid your problem (and the one I always use in real life) is to use the `QuotedStr()` function.  The same code would then become

```
aSQLText := 'INSERT INTO b_tbl (Name, Family) VALUES (%s, %s)'; 
aSQLCommand := Format(aSQLText, [QuotedStr(namee), QuotedStr(family)]);
```

According to the Online Help:

> Use QuotedStr to convert the string S to a quoted string. A single quote character (') >is inserted at the beginning and end of S, and each single quote character in the string is >repeated.

What it means by "repeated" is what I've referred to as "doubling up".  Why that's important, and the main reason I use QuotedStr is to avoid the Sql db-engine throwing an error when the value you want to send contains a single quote character as in *O'Reilly*.

Try adding a row containing that name to your table using MySql Workbench and you'll see what I mean.

So, not only does using QuotedStr make constructing SQL statements as strings in Delphi code less error-prone, but it also avoid problems at the back-end, too.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What error message do you get?  Btw, the code in your q looks fake (e.g. 'field' is spelt incorrectly), please don't do that, it just wastes everyone's time - paste your exact code and error message into your q.

Comment: that eror was same eror i asked
it doest change

Comment: See update - you **cannot** still be getting the same error if you have changed your code correctly.  You might still be getting an error, but not the *same* error.

Comment: im so tired with getting eror i change code correctly
`aSQLText:= 'INSERT INTO b_tbl(Name,Family) VALUES ('+'%s'+','+'%s'+')';`

Comment: That change is **not** what I said - it has only single quotes around the `%s`, it needs **two single quotes**.  Try displaying/printing `aSQLText` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: For further reference, see [Escape Sequences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html#idm139758901645024).

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite.  I initially showed the OP how to fix the prob by doubling the quotes, but in practice I'd use QuotedStr myself, so have added a bit about it to my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I saw. I also saw the comment where the OP said it didn't work because they'd not noticed that the quotes were doubled in each case. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this will help anybody else I had the same error when I was parsing a  python variable with a sql statement and it had an if statement in i.e.

```
sql="select bob,steve, if(steve>50,'y','n') from table;"
```

try as I might it coming up with this "unknown column y" - so I tried everything and then I was about to get rid of it and give it up as a bad job until I thought I would swap the " for ' and ' for "..... Hoooraaahh it works!
This is the statement that worked

```
sql='select bob,steve, if(steve>50,"y","n") from table;'
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this sort of problem and SQL injection you should really look into using SQL parameters for this, not the Pascal format statement.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.